# Creating dense matrix using org.javatuples.Pair and HashMap is too slow

Tags: java, matrix, hashmap, collision

I have a dense symmetric matrix of size about 30000 X 30000 that contains distances between strings. Since the distance is symmetric, the upper triangle of the matrix is stored in a tab-separated 3-column file of the form

```
stringA<tab>stringB<tab>distance
```

I am using `HashMap` and `org.javatuples.Pair` to create a map to quickly look up distances for given pairs of string as follows:

```
import org.javatuples.Pair;

HashMap<Pair<String,String>,Double> pairScores = new HashMap<Pair<String,String>,Double>();

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
String line = null;

while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String [] parts = line.split("\t");
    String d1 = parts[0];
    String d2 = parts[1];
    Double score = Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
    Pair<String,String> p12 = new Pair<String,String>(d1,d2);
    Pair<String,String> p21 = new Pair<String,String>(d2,d1);
    pairScores.put(p12, score);
    pairScores.put(p21, score);
}
```

`data.txt` is very big (~400M lines) and the process eventually slows down to a crawl with most time being spent in `java.util.HashMap.put`.

I don't think there should be (m)any hash code collisions on pairs but I might be wrong. How can I verify this? Is it enough to simply look at how unique `p12.hashCode()` and `p12.hashCode()` are?

If there are no collisions, what else could be causing to slow down?

Is there a batter way to construct this matrix for quick lookup?

Comment: Glancing at it, it looks like the `hashCode()` implementation is honestly pretty bad.  You'd be better off writing your own `Pair`, probably.  Also, doing a manual `split` instead of using `String.split`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Do you mean the `hashCode` implementation in `org.javatuples.Pair`? And thanks for the `split` suggestion, although now it only accounts for about 0.5% of processing time, according to the profiler

Comment: Yes, that is the implementation I mean; it's not even specialized for when you have two elements.

Comment: I would guess that the main bottleneck here is the file I/O. Did you measure the time of simply reading the file, not doing anything with it?

Comment: @radoh File I/O is not the issue. As Louis pointed out above, the problem is the `Pair`'s `hashCode()` which does indeed appear to produce lots of collisions for my data. I am experimenting with an alternative right now and will post it if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using [Guava's](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) `Table<Integer, Integer, Double>` after also realizing that my strings are unique enough that I could use their hashes, instead of the strings themselves, as keys, to reduce memory requirements. The creation of the table runs in reasonable time, however, there are issues with serializing and deserializing the resulting objects: I ran into out of memory errors even with the move from `String` to `Integer`. It seems to be working after I decided to not store both `a-b` and `b-a` pairs, but I might be balancing on the edge of what my machine can handle